# How can i add flex plugin to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder

I'm trying to create a web application using Flex in Front Office, so i tried to download the flex plugin for eclipse from http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flex_eclipse but the download dosen't launch, i tried with many pc and many navigator but i got the same problem. 
can any body help to download this plugin from another site? or tel me if there another way to use flex with eclipse?

Comment: it seems similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231701/how-to-add-flex-to-eclipse-ide) must help you

Answer (score 0):

You link seems to point to Flex builder 3, which is an old release (I wasn't able to authenticate with my adobe account, but there was an ad for Flex Builder 3.02)
And even your tags mentions FlexBuilder.
Adobe changed the name of this product to Flash Builder since release 4, in 2010.
So you shoud try to download it from the [current download page](https://creative.adobe.com/fr/products/flash-builder).
I'm not sure it's always available as a plugin, you may have to pick the full environment.